# Logging in for first time results in "Loading...."

Tags: installation, akeneo

I have just managed to install Akeneo 2.3 and have managed to get to the login screen where I have entered the default credentials (both app and app_dev).

Unfortunately all I now get is "Loading...." with dinosaurs being dropped into boxes.

Nothing appears to be reported in the either log files that is of any value (although I may not realise the importance of some entries).  The only 'error' which is reported as not being caught is that for some reason the favicon cannot be found although it is in the root of the webspace.....makes be wonder whether there is an issues with routing or permissions.

Other than that I haven't got any idea, nor do I really know where to start to find a solution.  Anybody got any pointers on what I can do to try and start debugging the problem?

I have previously been running version 1.8 as a prototype successfully.  Now moving to a later version, I have found a lot has changed....and am stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted the problem and now resolved it.

Digging in with the developer tools in Chrome, it was showing a 404 error for some AJAX calls.  But it also showed that the js file that was causing the error then provided a hint that the webserver wasn't configured correctly and that maybe mod_rewrite wasn't running properly.

Long story short, ensure  AllowOverride is set within your folder structure.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Restart Apache and problem is resolved.

Comment: I am having this issue now, and after adding Allowoverride All to apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf and apache2.conf, its still not working